# $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists$ a piecewise linear function $g$% such that for a continous function $f$

Tags: uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

How would I show the following
Edit

A function is called piecewise linear if it is (1)Continuous (2)Its graph consists of finitely many linear segments

Prove that a continuous function on an interval [a,b] is the uniform limit of a sequence of piece wise linear function.

---

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists$ a piecewise linear function $g$ such that for a continous function $f$

$|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall x \in E$

I am not sure how I would do this problem.

Comment: What is $E$? And you might want to check that absolute value again I think.

Comment: are sure you that this is uniformly in $f$?

Comment: I think E is a subset of all real mumbers.

Comment: @user251257yes I it is

Comment: It is uniformly continous

Comment: the way you phrased it, $f$ depends on $\epsilon$ and $g$. You probably means for **every** function $f:E\to\mathbb R$ and every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a piecewise linear function $g$ and so on...

Comment: you also probably want that $E$ is compact.

Comment: @user251257 Yes g is a sequence of pieceswise linear functions

Comment: yes it is compact because it is covered by finitely many linear segmets

Comment: your formulation makes no sense, as it is trivially true. take any the zero function for $g$ and $f$. Please edit you question.

Comment: Ok I will put up the entire question.

Comment: A continuous $f:[a.b]\to R$ is uniformly continuous, that is, $\forall e<0\;\exists d>0\;(|x-y|,d\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<e).$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous. For $n\in\mathbb N$ and $h_n = (b-a) / n$ define $x_{n,k} = a + kh_n$, $0\le k \le n$, and the piecewise linear function
$g_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$ g_n(x_{n,k}) = f(x_{n,k}). $$

**Claim:** $g_n \to f$ uniformly.

Hints:

1. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) -f(y)| < \epsilon$ holds for every $x,y\in[a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$.
2. There is a $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for $x_{n,k+1} - x_{n,k} = h_n = (b-a)/n < \delta$ for every $n\ge N$ and $1\le k \le n$.
3. Let $x\in [x_{n,k}, x_{n,k+1}]$. Wlog assume $f(x_{n,k}) \le f(x_{n,k+1})$.
   Then, we have
   $$ f(x_{n,k}) = g_n(x_{n,k}) \le g_n(x) \le g_n(x_{n,k+1}) \le f(x_{n,k+1}). $$

Could you bound $g_n(x) - f(x)$?

Comment: so h is the partion of the piece wise linear function I think

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: yes and $h$ depends on $n$. I will edit it

Comment: and the subscript $g_n$ the n here I think stand a certain piecewise function of the sequence of piece-wise function, which has it its limit as f

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: yes, for each $n$ you have a (possibly) different function $g_n$, so that they make up a sequence of functions. This sequence converges to $f$.

Comment: Then the second hint says when n is large enough, the size of the partitions become very small and can be bounded by delta.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: yes

Comment: The third hint slightly confuses me because how do you know what x is? I think it is a point between the interval of the partition,s but I am not sure would is say $g_n(x)=f(x)$ and x is bounded by $\delta$ in the second hint

Comment: so then $\forall \epsilon$ $\exists N \in$ natural number such that $|g_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $\forall$ $n \ge N$

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: $x$ is just **any** point in the subinterval $[x_{n,k}, x_{n,k+1}]$. Every $x\in[a,b]$ lands in one of the $n$ subintervals. **You** need to bound $|g_n(x) - f(x)|$ uniformly in $x$ to establish uniform convergence. (These are only hints, not the complete solution). And in the end you get something like $|g_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I think I see since the whole the difference of $x_{n,k+1}-x_{n,k}<\delta$ then the diffeence beteen any two point in this interval is less than delta

Comment: I will ponder it..